# Center custom login field in menu bar Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication, menu

I found this code to add a login & password field into the menu bar of my wordpress theme. Looks pretty good so far but very out of place..

```
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);

function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        // start buffering
        ob_start();
        // this is the actual form function
        wp_login_form($args); // $args optional see below ..
        // get buffering
        $loginoutform = ob_get_contents();
        // clean buffering
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= $loginoutform ; // concatenate buffering with items ...
    return $items;
}
```

It places itself on the right side underneath my main menu navigation. What I would like to do is have the login fields centered horizontally in the menu bar.

I would greatly appreciate any information or code to help me achieve the sleek login option I'm going for. Site is https://cypherbeats.com

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: It seems I have more on my plate than just this. The fields do not go away - or switch to "logout" When logged in. I am just learning the ropes of the editor in wordpress. I posted this into funtions.php as well.